# breqn package and equation numbering

Tags: breqn

I have the following problem with `breqn` package: I want to write a long equation and automatically split it with `dmath` environment. It is splitting equation perfectly, but placing the equation number one line below. I want to have a result such that last part of the equation and equation number are in the same line.

Here is the code I'm trying to fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
{{E}_{0}}\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty }\beta _{B}^{t}\left({{D}_{t+1}}+\left( 1+r_{f,t-1} \right)L_{f,t}+\left( 1+r_{g,t-1} \right)L_{g,t}+\left( 1+r_{i,t-1} \right)L_{i,t}-L_{f,t+1}-L_{g,t+1}-L_{i,t+1}-\left( 1+r_{p,t-1} \right){{D}_{t}} -\frac{{{\phi }_{f}}}{2} L_{f,t+1}^{2}-\frac{{{\phi }_{g}}}{2}L_{g,t+1}^{2}-\frac{\phi_{i}}{2}L_{i,t+1}^{2} \right)
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Thank you.

EDIT: I was told that the space in the second line is not enough to place the equation number. How about following case where I have exactly the same equation given in 3 line with more than enough space to place equation number in the same row:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Problem}
\begin{dmath}
{{E}_{0}}\sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty }\beta _{B}^{t}\left({{D}_{t+1}}+\left( 1+r_{f,t-1} \right)L_{f,t}+\left( 1+r_{g,t-1} \right)L_{g,t}+\left( 1+r_{i,t-1} \right)L_{i,t}-L_{f,t+1}-L_{g,t+1}-L_{i,t+1}-\left( 1+r_{p,t-1} \right){{D}_{t}} -\frac{{{\phi }_{f}}}{2} L_{f,t+1}^{2}-\frac{{{\phi }_{g}}}{2}L_{g,t+1}^{2}-\frac{\phi_{i}}{2}L_{i,t+1}^{2} \right)
\end{dmath}
\end{frame}\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently, `breqn` isn't willing to split the equation in three lines.

Comment: There is enough space in the second line to squeeze the equation number

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: please take a look at the layouts supported by `breqn`, as shown in the documentation (`texdoc breqn`).  `breqn` will not by itself set the final line so that it ends to the left of the next-to-last line unless there is a clear "preferable" breakpoint (sucn as an = sign) that mandates a more leftward placement.

Comment: That's a limitation of `breqn` (which has many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recommend `breqn` except when you don't want to bother with typesetting and are willing to accept poor output.

Apparently, the package is not keen into splitting the equation across three lines. Here is a better way to cope with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E_{0}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty }\beta _{B}^{t}
  \biggl(&D_{t+1}+(1+r_{f,t-1})L_{f,t}+(1+r_{g,t-1})L_{g,t} \\
        &+(1+r_{i,t-1})L_{i,t}-L_{f,t+1}-L_{g,t+1}-L_{i,t+1}\\
        &-(1+r_{p,t-1}){{D}_{t}} -\frac{\phi_{f}}{2} L_{f,t+1}^{2}
         -\frac{\phi_{g}}{2}L_{g,t+1}^{2}-\frac{\phi_{i}}{2}L_{i,t+1}^{2}
  \biggr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, as I previously mentioned there is no need for the 3rd line. There is enough space in the second line to accommodate the equation number

Comment: @TashkentYankee -- there is *not* sufficient space for the equation number unless the second line is shoved all the way to the left, and that violates the rules of `breqn`.  the supported layouts are illustrated in the documentation, and that isn't among them.

Comment: @TashkentYankee, enough place is only available if you make text width wider. For example with adding `usepackage{geometry}` to preamble of your MWE ...